# File getting deleted before processing

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I have spring xd module  with rabbit transport which pulls files from s3 and split line by line and delete it after processing(ExpressionAdvice) .I have around 1 million messages(lines) in my file which is in s3.The file gets downloaded to xd container  box  and i checked md5sum and its same and has same lines . I see only 260k odd message are coming to output channel which is processor.I am loosing around 740 messages. sometimes it random once i see all messages like 1 million in my output channel and sometimes only 250k .I am measuring this using counter for my stream.File is downloaded but i feel its getting deleted before processing  all records/lines in 10 seconds, my file size is around 700Mb.Please let me know if expression advice is deleting before processing.

```
 module.aws-s3-source.count=1 and module.aws-s3-source.concurrency=70
    stream1 as-s3-source |processor|sink

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:test-${region}.properties" />

    <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>


    <bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
        <constructor-arg ref="healthCheckStrategy"/>

    </bean>



    <bean id="healthCheckStrategy" class="test.ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy">
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="doHealthCheck" value="${doHealthCheck}"/>
        <property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="restTemplate"
          class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="requestFactory"/>

    </bean>


    <bean id="requestFactory"
          class="test.BatchClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="verifier"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="verifier"
          class="test.NullHostnameVerifier">

    </bean>


    <bean id="encryptedDatum" class="test.EncryptedSecuredDatum"/>




    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
        <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="test.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">

        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value=""/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">

    </bean>

    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${prefix}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

        <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
            </bean>
        </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-file:splitter>

    <int:channel-interceptor pattern="*" order="3">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap">
            <constructor-arg ref="loggingChannel" />
        </bean>
    </int:channel-interceptor>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" level="INFO"/>

    <int:channel id="output"/>

</beans>
```

Update 2 :

My stream is like below 
aws-s3-source|processor|http-client| processor> queue:testQueue

1)Now I split the stream like below:

```
 aws-s3-source> queue:s3Queue
```

I was able to  read all my 1 million messages very fast.
2)Now i added one more stream like below i see issue again was s3 stops pulling file and message are lost everytime

```
 queue:s3Queue>processor|http-client| processor> queue:testQueue
```

3)Observation is when i add http-client this issue happens again ,i.e. some message from input source is missing.

4)Now I split the file into 125 Mb 5 files instead of 660mb one file .ie 200 k records 5 files.I don't see the issue i get all my messages

I also see lot of messages clogging in queue before http-client .
I am thinking  is it something to do with memory or threading inside xd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please let me know if expression advice is deleting before processing.

No; the advice is an `around` advice around the message handler; it can't execute (evaluate the expression), until the splitter has emitted all the lines.

Is it possible the file is pulled from s3 before it's completely written?

To debug this problem, I would suggest changing the advice to send the file to another subflow and do some analysis/logging there before deleting.

Comment: No I was monitoring my local folder file gets pulled only after fully uploaded and also the file which is pulled and which is in s3 have same md5hash and size and number of lines.One observation I saw was after file gets pulled within 8-10sec it is deleted.I feel its not possible to process 1 million record in 10 sec

Comment: Well, nor is it possible for the advice to delete the file until the splitter has sent all the lines. You need to add debugging.

Comment: Let me check adding debugger

Comment: Please find my  observations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787785/spring-xd-loosing-messages-when-processing-huge-volume/35819392?noredirect=1#comment59309729_35819392 this helped