# spring xd losing messages when processing huge volume

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I am using spring xd My stream looks like below and running tests on 3 node container with 1 admin node with rabbit as transport

```
aws-s3|processor1|http-client|processor2>queue:readyQueue
```

I have created below tap.

```
tap1  aws-s3>s3Queue


tap2  processor1>processorQueue1

tap3  http-client>httpQueue
```

I run below scenarios in my tests:

`Scenario1`: 5 files of 200k =1 Million records
 concurrency of http-client=70  and processor2=30

I see 900k message  s3Queue

I see 889k message  processorQueue1

I see 886k message  httpQueue

I see 883k message  processorQueue2
Messages are lost everywhere and its random

```
Scenario2:
```

5 files of 200k =1 Million records and all module concurrency=1

I see 998800 message  s3Queue

I see 998760 message  processorQueue1

I see 997540 message  httpQueue

I see 997530 message  processorQueue2

Even this number is random and not consistent

```
Scenario3
```

I changed stream as below and concurrency=1  and 5 files of 200k =1 Million records

```
aws-s3 >testQueue
```

I get all my messages I run 3 times and no issues.I get all my 1 million messages

```
scenario4
```

I changed stream as below and concurrency=1 5 files of 200k =1 Million records

```
aws-s3 |processor1 >testQueue2
```

I get all my messages I run 3 times and no issues.I get all my 1 million messages

In scenario4 and scenarion 3 data ingestion is faster and it took 5  min to process 5 million faster and  ingestion was faster in rabbit transport queue like 5k msg per sec

In scenario 1 data ingestion was slower even s3 module was pulling the data very slow like 300 to 1000 msg per sec

In scenario 2 s3 pulled data faster but http client was slow like 100 msg per sec but aws-s3 pulled data fast like  3-4k msg per sec.

I am thinking like seeing xd threading is causing issues and i am losing messages.Please  can you help me how to solve this issue.

update

```
Scenario 5
```

I changed `reply-timeout` to `-1` in http client and then 
I lost only 37 msgs

Now again I run 2nd iteration I lost 25000 msgs i see the bellowing containers log when that happened

```
2016-03-04T03:42:04-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-7 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@b6700b1]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(RabbitMessageBus.java:891)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:282)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.monitorSend(DirectChannelMetrics.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.doInvoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.invoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1537.send(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
        at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:63)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:51)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:758)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$300(CachingConnectionFactory.java:747)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:419)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:364)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:357)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1100(CachingConnectionFactory.java:75)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:763)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createChannel(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:134)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:540)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:635)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:331)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:323)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        ... 93 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:125)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:134)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:499)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:44)
        ... 112 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:348)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:221)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
        ... 116 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 23364
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.getChannel(ChannelManager.java:80)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:552)
        ... 1 more

2016-03-04T03:42:05-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection xxx:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'xdbus.tap-s3.tap:stream:stream.batch-aws-s3-source.0' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)


2016-03-04T03:53:13-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection xxx:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
2016-03-04T03:53:13-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection xxx:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'xdbus.tap-s3.tap:stream:stream.batch-aws-s3-source.0' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
~                                                                                                                                                                                 


2016-03-04T02:57:54-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection xxx:8080 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
2016-03-04T02:57:55-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection xxx:8080 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
2016-03-04T03:42:04-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection yyy:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
```

Updated

I found the issue for message loses when this exception happens i see lot of msg lost.This pattern i tested multiple time.Everytime this exception happens i see msg lost.Also bumping up concurrency makes this issue to occur often.

```
2016-03-05T13:59:41-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR AMQP Connection host1:5672 connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: connection error
```

rabbit configuration

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
   addresses: host1:5672,host2:5672,host3:5672
   adminAddresses: http://host1:15672,http://host2:15672,http://host3:15672
   nodes: rabbit@host1.test.com,rabbit@host2.test.com,rabbit@host2.test.com
   username: test
   password: test
   virtual_host: /
   useSSL: false
   sslProperties:
```

updated with increasing cache size to 200

I added xml provided by you and increased cache size to 200.This is the  way happens when processing 1 million and  80 k  messages.Only my http client concurrency is 100 all other is 1 .Slowly processing stopped msg are still there before http-client queue and  same count.But msg count in my named channel slowly increasing like 10 msg per minute but its very slow 
s3-poller|processor|http-client>queue:batchCacheQueue

Msg not getting decreass  in queue before http  186174.But slowly msg are coming in to batchCacheQueue

[image]

Test case to simulate:

1)I was using spring integration aws-s3 source with a splitter in composite module | processor like xml parsing |http-client with concurrency 100 >named channel.

2)I think file source might also work.Create single file of million records and try to   pull this from file.

3)After some 4 to 5 run we see this exception happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 23364

We found an issue when channels are churned a lot; you need to increase the channel cache size in the rabbit caching connection factory.

See [this answer for a work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563064/processing-messages-through-namedchannels-with-prefetch-1/35584333#35584333).

I opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3747) so that the next version of Spring XD will expose this setting by in servers.yml so you don't have to override the bus configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Gary.I  found the issue for msg loss pls see my update.Let me know this is work around we should go.

Comment: Yes; increasing the cache size should solve it; I don't currently know the root cause of the unknown channel exception (I haven't been able to reproduce it in tests) but increasing the cache size avoids it.

Comment: I did updated this and msgs are hold up please see my update

Comment: Since you're not consuming from the named channel, perhaps you are running out of resources on the rabbit server. I see that queue is in `flow`. Perhaps look in the rabbit logs?

Comment: Again I was running similar test  with 200k records pulled from s3  every 10 min instead of 200k every 5 seconds.Now i do not see that issue.Adding delay  in ingestion helped.But also I changed concurrency of http-client to 10 from 100.But here  also  I am not consuming from namedChannel.Also in rabbit it says slaves Un synchronized and not able to delete or purge that namedChannel

Comment: Also I see that https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/4a75746d007ace35d395f16249b3313dddd38450/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java increase the channel cache for high concurrency?Was that the reason

Comment: A couple of people have reported the `UnknownChannelException`. We haven't tracked down the root cause but it seems that increasing the cache size is a work-around. I am not really clear if you still have an issue, but I can't really help with just the static data you provide. If you can reproduce your issue with a simple test case, we can take a look.

Comment: Sure adding test case

Comment: Increasing cache sized helps and not seeing the issue.But how to set cache size? If I am using more concurrency should i use more cache size?If i am using more modules or more streams should i increase cache size?

Comment: Channel checkouts for publishing messages is extremely short - it's difficult to provide a guideline without knowing more about your application. It generally won't hurt to see it to a high value - we'll only create as many channels as needed but it will typically be much less than the total number of threads publishing messages. In 1.6 we've added cache information to a JMX MBean so you can monitor the cache.

Comment: I faced similar issue like queue moved to flow state and system process very slow after sometime.We have many streams in production like 10 streams I am thinking like set cache size to 1000 .Is it ok or will this cause other performance issues?Just seeking your opinion.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem but you need to figure out why your rabbit is slowing down.